# find $x$ from $M = \sqrt \frac{2}{\cosh(2ax) + \cos(2bx)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to find the $x$ for this function? meaning that I will get $x=$ ?

$$M = \sqrt \frac{2}{\cosh(2ax) + \cos(2bx)}$$

I need to know what is $x$ given $M$, $a$ and $b$.

I tried with wolfram given that $a=1$ and $b=1$:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=M+%3D+(2%2F(cosh(2x)+%2B+cos(2x)))%5E0.5

but it say that there are not roots for $x$, even though it seems that this function is decreasing with $x$. (I need only the positive $x$ if it helps)

Some more constrains:

$M$ is positive, $a$ and $b$ are the real and imaginary part of  $\sqrt {1+i\omega \tau}$ respectively, $\omega$ is the angular velocity $\tau$ and is in ms. This means that a and b are both positive.

Comment: Note that $\cosh(2ax)+\cos(2bx)>1$, thus, there is no solution when $M>\sqrt2$.  And this is not possible to solve in general.  Maybe there is some hope when $a=b$ though.

Comment: can you tell us something to the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I edited the question and wrote created some constrains